# aws workflow re-run not working after some time

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

I wrote a workflow using aws flow framework for java. It is working fine. But I am facing an issue while trying to re-run this workflow after some time.

After registering this workflow's workers, re-run works fine till some time no matter how many times I try it but after that it suddenly stops working and gets stuck at DecisionTaskScheduled event and eventually times out. I checked the history and it shows "No Activities found for the given execution". Although if I manually re-register the activities, it again starts working. Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If a workflow execution is stuck at DecisionTaskScheduled event then workflow worker is not running or having some issue. I'm not sure what you mean by "registering workflow workers". Workflow type is registered only once and there is no need to reregister it. Workers are just running executing polls to SWF and processing decision tasks. Make sure that workflow worker is running and is not stuck for any reason.

Comment: By "registering workflow workers", I actually meant that I executed the workflow and activity hosts to start the decider and workers. It starts successfully when I execute those hosts but somehow, it is stopped after sometime(few hours in my case), due to which re-running the workflow gets stuck. If I again manually run the host, it starts working but that is the issue. I don't know why I have to re-execute those hosts every few hours.

Comment: I would recommend enabling logging to find out why these processes get into trouble. Also getting thread dump of such processes might also help.